Kalman Filter Update Step Covariance Form
I am trying to understand the update step in the Kalman Filter as expressed in covariance form.
Here is the notation I will use, so we are on the same page:
$x_{i+1}=A_ix_i+v_i$ where $v_i\sim N(0,Q_i)$ and $y_i=C_ix_i+w_i$ where $w_i\sim N(0,R_i)$. We also have $x_0\sim N(0,\Lambda_0)$.
I want to know how to prove the update equations in covariance form (I know how to do it in information form, this is relatively straightforward):
$\hat{\mu}_i=\hat{\mu}_{i|i-1}+K_iz_i$ and $\hat{\Lambda}_i=\hat{\Lambda}_{i|i-1}+K_i\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}K_i^\intercal$ where $z_i=y_i-C_i\hat{\mu}_{i|i-1}$ is the innovation and $K_i=\Lambda_{x_i,z_i}\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}^{-1}$ is the Kalman Gain.
And just to clarify, these means are all means of causal posteriors, i.e. $\mu_i$ is the mean of $p(x_i|x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},y_1,\dots,y_i)$ and $\mu_{i|i-1}$ is the mean of $p(x_i|x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},y_1,\dots,y_{i-1})$.

So what is the easiest way to prove this? I tried 1) converting from the information form update equation and 2) calculating those covariances in $K_i$ and simplifying, but I keep running into the inverse of the addition of matrices which seems hard to simplify.
For example, if I try to compute $\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}$ I end up with something like
$$\Lambda_{z_i,z_i}=C_i(\hat{\Lambda}_i-\hat{\mu}_i\hat{\mu}_i^\intercal)C_i+R_i$$
which simply does not seem ot have a nice inverse we can simplify when plugging into $K_i$. Any help would be appreciated!
